# Round up number to nearest 9

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I've got a number 99, I want to multiply it by 1.2 which gives 118.8, and then round it up to the nearest 9 to get 119.

Another example is having 119, divided by 1.2 = 99.16, rounded to the nearest nine would be equal to 99.

I've started doing it like so :

```
var number = 99
var numberMultiplied = number * 1.2
var numberRounded = Math.round(numberMultiplied / 9)*9
console.log(numberRounded )
```

But it gives me 117 rather than 119 ... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 119 is not a multiple of 9. Are you really looking for multiples of 9 or just for the last digit(s) to be 9?

Comment: "what am I doing wrong" - that code rounds to the nearest __multiple__ of 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to offset the number by 1 and take advantage of the fact that you already know how to round to nearest 10:

```
var numberRounded = Math.round((numberMultiplied + 1) / 10)*10 - 1;
```

Comment: The only thing I would add is that you need to get two numbers ending with 9 and then check which one is closest to original.

Answer (score 1):

First, round the number to the **nearest tenth**:

```
Math.round(++numberMultiplied / 10) * 10
```

and then **subtract 1** from it!

```js
var number = 99
var numberMultiplied = number * 1.2
var numberRounded = Math.round(++numberMultiplied / 10) * 10 - 1
console.log(numberRounded)
```

Comment: I think this would be more sound if the original number was offset *before* the rounding, then offset back.

Comment: @SamiHult what do you mean by the original number was offset?

Comment: @gumakettell This answer was later corrected to do exactly that (it's the `++` before `numberMultiplied`). The problem of rounding to the nearest 9 is the same as rounding to nearest 10 if the number *is off by one*, offset by one. Simply put, you need to add a value before the rounding and then subtract that same value afterwards, such as in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 cases:
1: if the multiplied number is 173 then the number is closer to 169
2: if the multiplied number is 177 then the number is closer to 179

You could do something like this:

```
var divNumber = multipliedNumber / 10;
var modNumber= multipliedNumber % 10 ;
if(modNumber < 5){ divNumber = divNumber * 10 - 1 }else{ divNumber = divNumber * 10 + 9 }
```